# Only last row is being inserted in the table in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working on a java project using hibernate. I have a `csv` file that contains more than 200 data. I've successfully retrieved data from `csv` file. Now I have to insert those data to the table.

The problem is only the last row is being added to the table. Other rows are not being inserted.

The schema of the table is given below:

```
INSERT INTO `attendence_table`
(`serial_no` int auto-increment, 
`employee_id` varchar2, 
`in_time` varchar2, 
`out_time` varchar2,
 `attend_date` date)
```

The Attendence class is given below:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "attendence_table")
   public class Attendence {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "serial_no")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private String employee_id;
    @Column(name = "in_time")
    private String inTime;
    @Column(name = "out_time")
    private String outTime;
    @Column(name = "attend_date")
    private String date;



    public String getEmployee_id() {
        return employee_id;
    }

    public void setEmployee_id(String employee_id) {
        this.employee_id = employee_id;
    }

    public String getInTime() {
        return inTime;
    }

    public void setInTime(String inTime) {
        this.inTime = inTime;
    }

    public String getOutTime() {
        return outTime;
    }

    public void setOutTime(String outTime) {
        this.outTime = outTime;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

   }
```

The insert function is given below:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

public static void hibernateInsertAttendenceSession(List<Attendence> collection) {


    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    for (Attendence obj : collection) {
        session.save(obj);
        System.out.println("Object Added");

    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

For your convenience, I'm also adding the glimpse of the csv file:

```
Test_company,TestId001,Test Name,2018/03/22,08:53:15,17:50:40
Test_company,TestId001,Test Name,2018/03/25,08:51:02,17:55:18
Test_company,TestId001,Test Name,2018/03/27,08:50:16,18:03:47
Test_company,TestId001,Test Name,2018/03/28,08:48:07,18:46:42
Test_company,TestId001,Test Name,2018/03/29,08:56:16,20:14:16
```

Thanks in advance for giving your valuable time to help me with this issue.

Comment: The problem is that dummy variable `obj` is going out of scope/getting overwritten with each loop iteration.  Your approach can't be the right way to do this.

Comment: But during each iteration I'm saving the object to the session.

Comment: Check the sql generated and post it.
Also are you positive the collection does in fact contains all the Attendence you are expecting it to?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the reference of the `Attendence` object, while you're modifying it's content everytime.

You should probably instantiate an `Attendence` Object every time you attempt saving it.

```
for (Attendence obj : collection) {
    Attendence newRef = new Attendence(obj);
    session.save(newRef);
    System.out.println("Object Added");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, My issue was in different place. Thank you all for your help. While retrieving data from csv file, there was a little error which created the issue. Thank you all for your time :)

In the readfromcsv function, previously I did the following:

```
public static void readFromExcel(String path) {

    ArrayList<Attendence> attendences = new ArrayList<Attendence>();
    String csvFile = path;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    Attendence attendenceLine=new Attendence();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        //Attendence attendenceLine = new Attendence();
        line = br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            if (data.length == 6) {

                attendenceLine.setEmployee_id(data[1]);
                attendenceLine.setDate(data[3]);
                attendenceLine.setInTime(data[4]);
                attendenceLine.setOutTime(data[5]);

            }
            else{
                attendenceLine.setEmployee_id(data[1]);
                attendenceLine.setDate(data[3]);
                attendenceLine.setInTime("no punch");
                attendenceLine.setOutTime("no punch");
            }
            attendences.add(attendenceLine);
        }
        for(Attendence attendence: attendences){
            HibernateOperation.hibernateInsertOneAttendenceSession(attendence);
        }
        //HibernateOperation.hibernateInsertAttendenceSession(attendences);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddToDatabaseOperation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddToDatabaseOperation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here the attendenceLine String Variable was only having the last row as a reference value. Thats why for every iteration, I need to create the object again. I did the following to solve the issue.

```
public static void readFromExcel(String path) {

    ArrayList<Attendence> attendences = new ArrayList<Attendence>();
    String csvFile = path;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        //Attendence attendenceLine = new Attendence();
        line = br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            Attendence attendenceLine=new Attendence();
            if (data.length == 6) {

                attendenceLine.setEmployee_id(data[1]);
                attendenceLine.setDate(data[3]);
                attendenceLine.setInTime(data[4]);
                attendenceLine.setOutTime(data[5]);

            }
            else{
                attendenceLine.setEmployee_id(data[1]);
                attendenceLine.setDate(data[3]);
                attendenceLine.setInTime("no punch");
                attendenceLine.setOutTime("no punch");
            }
            attendences.add(attendenceLine);
        }
        for(Attendence attendence: attendences){
            HibernateOperation.hibernateInsertOneAttendenceSession(attendence);
        }
        //HibernateOperation.hibernateInsertAttendenceSession(attendences);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddToDatabaseOperation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddToDatabaseOperation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please call new class and add all filed to this new class and save new class.
It will work.

```
 for (Attendence obj : collection) {
        Attendence newRef = new Attendence();
        newRef.setSerialNo(obj.getSerialNo())
        // set newRef to obj of all column......
        session.save(newRef);
        System.out.println("Object Added");

    }
```